# Asmack android: Create a custom packet and register extension

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am using the library Asmack to use XMPP on an android app, the server sends custom Stanza

```
<notification xmlns="jabber:client" from="admin@api.pp.gs" to="1eef368606cb459b847809a0430bfa1f@api.pp.gs/iMac-de-Thomas" id="1457247499">
<body>lol</body>
</notification>
```

I would like to be able to listen these packets, I try to use PacketExtensionProvider but without success. Here my code to listen the packet:

```
xmppConnection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener()
{
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet)
    {
        Log.i("K:", "cool " + packet.getClass().toString());
    }
}, new MyPaquetFilter());
```

*Where MyPaquetFilter return always true for test purpose.*

How should I use the **PacketManager**, **PacketExtension** stuff in order to get my custom paquet here?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to receive a custom packet you need to first create a [Provider, either an IQProvider or an PacketExtensionProvider](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/providers.html), and register that Provider with [ProviderManager](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/provider/ProviderManager.html), so that's considered for parsing when receiving a packet.

You didn't showed us your custom PacketExtensionProvider nor how you are registering it with the ProviderManager. And just to absolute precise, you need to wrap your custom extension `notification` within the `message` element if you use PacketExtensionProvider.

Comment: Yes. In XMPP you either send custom payload under a custom element of, depending on the use case, IQ or Message.

Comment: yep, this is the way to go.

Comment: Which XML sent? Please elaborate.

Comment: The XML in the question (notification root node), I am sure if its the right way to go or should I use <message or <ig root note instead?

Comment: No standard compliant server will route stanzas that are not messages or IQ, that's why I said "In XMPP you either send custom payload under a custom element of, depending on the use case, IQ or Message."